# ruby on rails recursive sub-string

Tags: ruby, datetime, split

I have the string (actually it's a date and time) like this `"20120207080000"`.

Is there any option to split the given string using any pattern matching technique or anything else?

i.e I need the output like this

```
output = ["2012", "02", "07", "08", "00", "00"]
```

Otherwise is it possible to convert the given string into date/time object?.

ruby version: 1.8.7

Answer (score 8):

```
"20120207080000".unpack('A4A2A2A2A2A2') #=> ["2012", "02", "07", "08", "00", "00"]
```

Answer (score 4):

Get a DateTime object like this:

```
require 'date'
DateTime.strptime('20120207080000', '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
```

Please take care that you are using the right order of elements. I was just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

@steenslag answer is really a good answer although you can also do just using string manipulation .

```
str = "20120207080000"
output = [str[0..3], str[4..5], str[6..7], str[8..9], str[10..11], str[12..13]]
```

result :

```
["2012", "02", "07", "08", "00", "00"]
```

Comment: There's also `[str[0, 4]] + str[4..-1].scan(/../)` if you like string wrangling.